# Elastic search exception error in magento2

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have configured elastic search in magento2 after that will get exception error below :
I am not able to replicate where exactly the issue.  Please help me out.

> ```
> report.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [from].","line":1,"col":9}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [from].","line":1,"col":9},"status":400}
> ```

```
\"index_uuid\":\"E4sGUgAESdGLiRcn_lh-iw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v1\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"number_format_exception\",\"reason\":\"For input string: \\\"sdasd\\\"\"}}}]},\"status\":400} at /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:636)"}{
    "match" : {
      "_search" : {
        "query" : "sdasd",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 2.0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "match" : {
      "name" : {
        "query" : "sdasd",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 11.0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "match" : {
      "sku" : {
        "query" : "sdasd",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 8.0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "match" : {
      "manufacturer_value" : {
        "query" : "sdasd",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 7.0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "match" : {
      "short_description" : {
        "query" : "sdasd",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 6.0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "match" : {
      "color_value" : {
        "query" : "sdasd",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 2.0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "match" : {
      "price_0_1" : {
        "query" : "sdasd",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 2.0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "match" : {
      "tax_class_id_value" : {
        "query" : "sdasd",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 2.0
      }
    }
  }
],
"adjust_pure_negative" : true,
"minimum_should_match" : "1",
"boost" : 1.0
```

}
}\"index_uuid\":\"E4sGUgAESdGLiRcn_lh-iw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v1\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"number_format_exception\",\"reason\":\"For input string: \\"sdasd\\"\"}}}]},\"status\":400} at /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:636)"}

Comment: Add your query structure here.

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy query has been updated over comment, please review

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy , can you please share your inputs.

Comment: Are you trying to match the query string `sdasd` with multiple fields?